# excel macro to copy data on a loop until a blank row is hit error

Tags: vba, excel, loops, macros

I am trying to write a macro with VBA that will copy the data from my table in a sheet tiled "Front End" to a table on another sheet called "Raw Data". these two table are picture below

[image]

for now I am only dealing with the green table above

[image]

here is my code so far for the copying and pasting into the other sheet in the next empty row:

```
Sub transfer()
    Dim x As Long
'set starting point at row 8
    x = 8
    Dim BlankFound As Boolean
'defines the sheet the data is being coppied from
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet: Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Front End")
'defines the sheet the data is being pasted into
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")

    Do While BlankFound = False

'selects the next row where the 1st column is empty
        lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'pastes the data from the specified cells into the next empty row
            'destSheet.range("A" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("C2").Value
 destSheet.range("M" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("E2").Value
 destSheet.range("N" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("E4").Value
 destSheet.range("P" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("G4").Value
 destSheet.range("Q" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("C4").Value
 destSheet.range("O" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("I3").Value
 destSheet.range("B" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("Bx").Value
 destSheet.range("L" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("Cx").Value
 destSheet.range("F" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("Dx").Value
 destSheet.range("G" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("Ex").Value
 destSheet.range("I" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("Gx").Value
 destSheet.range("K" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("Hx").Value
 destSheet.range("H" & lMaxRows + 2).Value = sourceSheet.range("Nx").Value

        x = x + 1
        If Cells(x, "E").Value = "" Then
        BlankFound = True
        end if
    Loop
End sub
```

I need to have the macro copy each row from the green table to the next empty row in the "Raw Data" sheet until the macro hits an "actual cycles", column E, that is empty.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I never understand why people know they need a loop then proceed not to google loop XD

Comment: I did google loop, the main thing i dont understand is how to change the copy/paste statement so that they dont just copy the same cell however many times the loop is run

Comment: Then please put the code for your loop in your OP so we can help you.

Comment: I updated what ive tried so far, like i said, what i dont understand is how to get the data to copy from each new row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the same way you found your next cell to paste in.

`LastRow = sourceSheet.range("E8").end(xldown).row`  Then

`For curRow = 8 to LastRow`

Or to check for actual blanks something like `Do while sourcesheet.range("E" & curRow).value<>""`

Comment: i updated the code with the stuff i tried for looping now it just doesnt copy any data at all

Comment: also i get an error that just says "400" and the solution i used to fix it before is already in place

Comment: Your loop looks fine, a bit unconventional in that the if statement is only doing something that can be defined directly in the loop statement.  But it shouldn't be giving you any errors and should break when the cell is equal to "" like you want.

Comment: what about in that long list of copy/pastes where i define the row number as the value of x? when i run the macro step by step it give me an error that says "application defined or object defined error"

Comment: You don't define the row number as the value of x. In the source sheet row values are hardcoded.  In destsheet they are defined by lMaxRows+2.  Try going through a walkthrough on loops.  It will probably take you less then an hour and will give you a couple working examples on how to use variables in loops

Comment: sorry i forgot to update the code when i updated my comment, ill see what i can figure out, thanks for the help

Comment: use range("B" & x) for using a variable.